# Using MNIST to print larger numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

The MNIST dataset has all 10 numbers to train with. If I predict a `9`, the model will give as output a `9`. But, what if I want to predict the number `34.542`? It will give me a wrong number, since I have only trained from 0 to 9. So, how could I predict a `> 9` number?

This is my code, but I think it will not be useful here

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

    # Compiling and optimizing model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # Training the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

Comment: You can't expect to get correct prediction of a number that does not exist in training set.

Comment: but can each number of `34.542` be sectioned or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can't apply your model directly on an image of a large number.
You have to :

- apply a detection (localization) model to find and separate each digit. You'll get a bounding box for each digit.
- apply your classification model on the extracted image of each bounding box, to get the prediction on the separated digits.

See [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-multi-digit-detector-with-keras-and-opencv-b97e3cd3b37) for example.